# Generated ids in Apollo graphQL state

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

we are using Apollo 1.9.x with React and Server-side rendering. When we do `store.getState()` on the server and output that to the HTML, it contains a lot of ids with value of `$ROOT_QUERY.path.to.item.0.etc`. I’ve tried adding id fields to the data, but that doesn’t change the output from the store. Is there a way to get actual id values instead of those generated path-based ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to figure it out myself. As it turns out, if you add id fields to each type and then also add them to your query, the Apollo data is built using those ids.